# how to send one email to multiple recipents in sendgrid email in c# using smtp api

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, sendgrid, bulk

Scenario is that i have thousands of email which i want to send email 
With the help of this ( i am using asp.net with C#)
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/csharp.html
i can iterate all the emails and send emails to them (body of HTML is same and recipients are different)
but this is taking too much time.

**Things i done**
i have tried to add multiple recipent in "To" and send but this shows all the emails to every one 
i have tired to add multiple recipents in BCC and it shows undiscolsed

i have read that SendGrid manage this that it take values from To and send it one by one

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: You should really consider using the [SendGrid Marketing API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/index.html) for those sorts of emails.

Answer (score 1):

From their documentation @ https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html for the TO command

> This can also be passed in as an array, to send to multiple locations. Example: to[]=a@mail.com[]=b@mail.com. Note that recipients passed in this parameter will be visible as part of the message. If you wish to hide the recipients, use the TO parameter in the x-smtpapi header.

and following the link gives this example for the x-smtpapi header

```
{
  "to": [
    "<ben@example.com>",
    "Joe Smith <joe@example.com>"
  ]
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted , but now issue is that my emails are landing in spam :(

Comment: also how can i get status of emails which i send

Comment: Typically with email you can not get the status.  If your emails are being recognized as spam, i'm sure there are documents online how to make emails less spammy (send from a valid email address, include valid unsubscribe links, have a certain amount of production in the email content...)

I searched google for "how to make my emails not spam" and found this link https://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/